# shouldComponentUpdate won't receive the newest state

Tags: refluxjs

I use `Reflux.connect` methods to change component state, but I can't get the different part in `shouldComponentUpdate` between `nextState` and `this.state`. Actually, `this.state` already has the new values I was expecting to be in `nextState` when `shouldComponentUpdate` is called.

What should I need to do when I want to use shouldComponentUpdate with Reflux?

```
  var component = React.createClass({
     mixins: [Reflux.connect(store1, 'store1data'),
              Reflux.connect(store2, 'store2data')],

     shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        //Here this.state.store1data is equal to nextState.store1data
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're not mutating the state and instead returning a new copy of it. If your store only changes the field **inside the state**, then the `this.state` pointer already points to the mutated state.

so in your store1, instead of:

```
store1Data.someKey = newValue;
this.trigger(store1Data)
```

try doing:

```
store1Data = _.assign({}, store1Data, {someKey: newValue}); // this uses lodash, for example
this.trigger(store1Data)
```

That way you will get a fresh copy of store1Data every time it changes.

Immutability is an important concept when working with states, especially in React/Flux, since it allows you to determine quickly whether a state was changed. Try making a habit of always returning a new copy when changing the state, and to never change to anything inside the state unless you clone it first.

[Immutablity in React](http://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-react/)
[ImmutableJs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)